# Django Email Attachment: TypeError: 'File' object does not support indexing

Tags: django, email-attachments

EDIT:  I can send attachments on my local machine, but not on Heroku.  I changed the attach code to this:

```
if docfile:
    email.attach_file(docfile.name)
```

This works locally, in the shell and when I'm running my app's localhost server.

---

So I've been trying to make django send emails with attachments that are stored as File objects in a story model. I have a task that handle this:

```
from celery import task
from django.core.mail.message import EmailMessage
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
from apps.account.models import UserProfile

@task(name='send-email')
def send_published_article(sender, subject, body, attachment=None):
    recipients = []
    for profile in UserProfile.objects.all():
        if profile.user_type == 'Client':
            recipients.append(profile.user.email)
    email = EmailMessage(subject, body, sender, recipients)
    try:
        docfile = default_storage.open(attachment.name, 'w+')
        if docfile:
            email.attach_file(docfile.name)
        else:
            pass
    except:
        pass
    email.send()
```

I've been trying to find the bug with the shell, and everything seems great until I get to the last line, and run email.send().  The shell barfs up this error trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/vagrant/nns/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 248, in send
return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/home/vagrant/nns/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/console.py", line 23, in send_messages
self.stream.write('%s\n' % message.message().as_string())
  File "/home/vagrant/nns/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 215, in message
msg = self._create_message(msg)
  File "/home/vagrant/nns/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 272, in _create_message
return self._create_attachments(msg)
  File "/home/vagrant/nns/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 285, in _create_attachments
msg.attach(self._create_attachment(*attachment))
  File "/home/vagrant/nns/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 312, in _create_attachment
attachment = self._create_mime_attachment(content, mimetype)
  File "/home/vagrant/nns/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 300, in _create_mime_attachment
Encoders.encode_base64(attachment)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/encoders.py", line 45, in encode_base64
encdata = _bencode(orig)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/encoders.py", line 31, in _bencode
hasnewline = (s[-1] == '\n')
  TypeError: 'File' object does not support indexing
```

Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the file mode (I needed to use 'r').  Credit to both Tomita and Manjunath for partial answers.  Thanks.

```
from celery import task
from django.core.mail.message import EmailMessage
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
from apps.account.models import UserProfile

@task(name='send-email')
def send_published_article(sender, subject, body, attachment=None):
    recipients = []
    for profile in UserProfile.objects.all():
        if profile.user_type == 'Client':
            recipients.append(profile.user.email)
    email = EmailMessage(subject, body, sender, recipients)
    if attachment:
        email.attach(attachment.name, 'r')
    email.send()
```

Comment: Don't know what kind of object `attachment` was, but `attachment.file.read()` should probally work to. Furthermore, not loving the try except.

Comment: @Blackeagle52 If you're not loving the try except, what's the better way? I'm fully willing to admit there is a better way, and would love to see it.

Comment: First of all I would add an `if attachment`, just to make sure you won't get an AttributeError on `attachment.name`.
Second, I would also remove the `else: pass`, but it is possible you have a bit of your own code there.
Third, I would specify which kind of `Error` you are expecting, e.g. `IOError`. If you just want to prevent any possible crash you could change the empty case of except to Error and add a logger to output the `type()`/`repr()` of the Error. This way you will always be up to date about the errors during the execution of your method.

Comment: When I went to compare this to the existing code, I realized that I'd refactored this code months ago when I was on a test-writing / refactoring spree. Here's the code that I ended up with, which isn't too far off from what you suggested: https://github.com/AnthonyBRoberts/NNS/blob/master/apps/story/tasks.py

I guess I could edit the answer? This is sorta old.

Comment: Altough this looks way better, you just removed the answer of using the `storage.read` method. :p

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that you're passing a file to the attach function and not the file contents.

Call `read()` on the file object.

```
docfile = default_storage.open(attachment.name, 'w+')
if docfile:
    email.attach(docfile.name, docfile, 'image/jpg')
                                   #  ^^ should be docfile.read()
```

Comment: So at least on Heroku, I had to use the file mode 'r' to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

```
if docfile:
        email.attach(docfile.name, docfile.read(), docfile.content_type)
```

Comment: I tried this and got a different error:  

File "<console>", line 1, in <module>  

IOError: [Errno 71] Protocol error --  That one line is the entire trace